# Card guessing game, second card won't draw mid thread

Tags: android

mid project here and looking for a quick and dirty way out of a sticky situation.

The game looks like this. To play, click a card, and click another, and if they match they both stay shown. Match all and game is over.

[image]

In my case, when I have one card shown, when the user selects the second card, the processing logic, should set the card to be visible AND ONLY THEN, check if there is a match. And if not, return the card back to the old image.

This code, I hope, helps you understand what I'm trying to do.

```
    gridLayout.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //HOW DO I FORCE THE INTERFACE TO REDRAW BEFORE CONTINUING THE THREAD?
            engine.setCardStateToShow(position);
            gridLayout.invalidate();
            gridLayout.invalidateViews();
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch (Exception x){

            }
            //DETERMINE IF THE CARDS MATCH AND IF NOT -- SET CARD INVIS
            String message = engine.itemClicked(position, gridLayout);
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //If engine returns a value of WASWINNER, we can end the activity and end the game.
            if (message.equals(GameEngine.WASWINNER)) {
                startActivity(endActivity);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The final result as it stands, is the application changes the image to show, checks for match, if no match changes to not show. And only afterwards, re-draws the interface again with the new values, so to the end user, if there was no match, they never see the "wrong" tile, because it is reverted back to "not show."

Thanks in advance and please correct me if the question could have been asked better.

Comment: Please post don't post screenshots of code. Please post all text as text.

Comment: Sorry I'm still relatively new here. I will try find and read the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to resolve this issue making use of the AsyncTask abstract class. By using AsyncTask, I effectively could "multi thread", separating the comparison logic from the UI logic. As a result, I could manage the UI directly and seperately as shown in the basic explanation below.

By using the onPreExecute() I showed the cards.

BY using doInBackground() I could check and set card show state processing.

By using onPostExecute() I could return the cards to their final view state, directly in the UI thread, based on the results from the DoInBackground() method of the AsyncTask implementation.